# CW magnetron operation

Tags: rf, switching, magnetron

What limits the duty cycle for turning the magnetron of a microwave oven on?

What is the maximum width of the magnetron turning on time in one cycle,
if the switching cycle is 30 seconds (on + off).

Can I keep a magnetron oscillating continuously for several minutes?

Answer (score 1):

> What limits the duty cycle for turning the magnetron of a microwave oven on?

Heating up

The other questions depend on your specific magnetron and how your specific microwave oven cools it. We can't know that, you will have to ask the engineer that designed your specific microwave oven.

Note that this all sounds like you're about to play with magnetrons without proper understanding and therefore, without knowing what safety precautions you need. **Don't**. You stand a high chance of injuring yourself, to the point of death.

These devices have one purpose: heating food. They are far from stable enough for any usage that needs stable frequency (like for communications), and you're clearly not yet in a position to build a complex device that could be safe.